# Where should I ask a computer network question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to know what kind of information is passed to my network adapter when I hooked on the network with my PC.

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: You might want to clarify that question a bit. What exactly do you mean by "when I hooked on the network"? Do you mean "when I plug it in" (i.e. you're interested in knowing what happens right after a cable is plugged into the card), or something else?

Comment: @Mat Please check http://superuser.com/questions/397684/pc-network-bewilderment

Comment: This too broad a question in my opinion. A correct, complete answer would require a whole book (or at least a few chapters).

Comment: Much too broad. Voted to close it for the reasons @Mat stated. In fact, we're already getting the link-only ("here's a book") answers.

Comment: Of course one could always [make their own book](http://www.wireshark.org)...

Answer (score 6):

If the question is no more than what you've written above, then it's appropriate nowhere.  It's much, much too broad.  But if you have a specific question about your network adapter, then I think [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be the best place.  Per their faq:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: @osager - well an SU mod may come flame me for telling you to put wrong stuff on his site, so let's wait a minute or two and see if I'm actually right :)

Comment: [su] sounds about right to me.  Depending on what exactly you're looking for though (this question as it is, is a little vague), [security.se] may also be able to help.

Comment: The question wasn't related to any practical problem and would probably be considered too broad for any SE site, as it'd require a whole book about TCP/IP networking as an answer. Not bashing you for misdirecting, but please also check the "Which questions not to ask" section in our FAQ, I guess it's the same as anywhere else on the network :)

Comment: @slhck - I completely assumed the question was more in depth, with more details, and less broad than what OP wrote above.  But yeah, the question in this meta post is much, much too broad.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The question [was posted on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/397684/pc-network-bewilderment) already, FYI.

Comment: @slhck - you called it - that essentially was the question, and it's now closed on SU.